# display ASCII control characters in Emacs GUD (gdb) mode

Tags: emacs, gdb, ascii, gud

Programs I debug output a lot of debug using ascii ctrl characters for colors, bold etc.
In GUD mode they appear as "^[[...m".

Is there a way to have that output like it would be in a console?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ansi-color.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiColor) which is part of Emacs now. You can add a hook to `gdb-mode` (I think that's what it's called) to automatically set this up when you go into gud.

Comment: You are right! I have stopped trying ansi-color because it never worked for me in the past when I used older emacs. Thanks!

Comment: @chrisxxyy How did you achieve it? I tried on Emacs 24.4 but never succeeded.