# How do I display ANSI color codes in emacs for any mode?

Tags: emacs, ansi-escape

I have a log file that uses ANSI escape color codes to format the text. The mode is `fundamental`. There are other answered questions that address this issue but I'm not sure how to apply it to this mode or any other mode. I know the solution has something to do with configuring `ansi-color` in some way.

- [ANSI codes in shell mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256264/how-do-i-get-emacs-shell-mode-to-either-render-or-ignore-my-colors-instead-of)
- [ANSI codes in gdb mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674255/display-ascii-control-characters-in-emacs-gud-gdb-mode)

Comment: https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color

Comment: Given the limitations / complexity when using `emacs` - you might want to try a common alternative with large logfiles: `less -R /path/to/file.log`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use code below

```
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Then you can execute `display-ansi-colors` via M-x, via a key-binding of your choosing, or via some programmatic condition (maybe your log files have a extension or name that matches some regexp)

If you want to do this with read-only buffers (log files, grep results), you may use `inhibit-read-only`, so the function will be:

```
(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: @Avery, yes. Also, if anyone else is wondering how to do it, adding this to your .emacs will turn on ansi-color display for all `.log` files (choose your file extension appropriately):`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.log\\'" . display-ansi-colors))`

Comment: I am trying this for coloring my ack results (http://beyondgrep.com/). The result buffer is read-only and this solution does not work.

Comment: @juanleon: that is GREAT! Now only need to make the links from the search results work, but that is another question.

Comment: This is weird. I had used a similar solution to apply this after some compilation (that runs tests). when trying this function on a file with `[0m[32m[    OK    ] [0mfetches the definintion for the correct view` put either into a scratch buffer, or a new file called foobar.example, this doesn't work, was the stuff I was copy-pasting not correct ansi-color?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this (e.g. process escape sequences and display ansi colors) without modifying the file ?

Comment: ansi-color-apply-on-region works nice but seems prohibitively slow (30 seconds to process a 13,000-line region).

Comment: As @lungang-fang mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378271/how-do-i-display-ansi-color-codes-in-emacs-for-any-mode#comment134063460_61594508) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76014429/374851), if you are using emacs 28.2 or above ` ansi-color-apply-on-region` accepts the 3rd parameter "preserve-sequences". So we can make @juanleon's answer better. ```(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max) t)))```

Comment: I'm using an older version of Emacs.  I found that using "(undo)" before the second last closing parenthesis would keep the file from getting modified, while keeping the faces applied.

Answer (score 10):

User defined function:

```
(defun my-ansi-color (&optional beg end)
  "Interpret ANSI color esacape sequence by colorifying cotent.
Operate on selected region on whole buffer."
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point-min) (point-max))))
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region beg end))
```

For buffers that uses comint/compilation use filter:

```
(ignore-errors
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (defun my-colorize-compilation-buffer ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode)
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max))))
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'my-colorize-compilation-buffer))
```

Answer (score 9):

Gavenkoa's and Juanleon's solutions worked for me, but were not satisfying as they were modifying the contents of the file I was reading.

To colorize without modifying the contents of the file, download [tty-format.el](ftp://download.tuxfamily.org/user42/tty-format.el) and add the following to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "path/to/your/tty-format.el/")

(require 'tty-format)

;; M-x display-ansi-colors to explicitly decode ANSI color escape sequences                                                                                                                                        
(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (format-decode-buffer 'ansi-colors))

;; decode ANSI color escape sequences for *.txt or README files                                                                                                                                                    
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'tty-format-guess)

;; decode ANSI color escape sequences for .log files                                                                                                                                                               
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.log\\'" . display-ansi-colors))
```

tty-format is based on ansi-color.el which is only shipped natively with recent versions of emacs.

Comment: This worked for me, however, a warning - don't attempt this on large files! I just tried it with a 9 meg log file and it locked up emacs

Answer (score 1):

On large files, performance of `ansi-color-apply-on-region` is slow. Here's a solution that colors the current region and works with read-only buffers.

```lisp
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun ansi-color-region ()
  "Color the ANSI escape sequences in the acitve region.
Sequences start with an escape \033 (typically shown as \"^[\")
and end with \"m\", e.g. this is two sequences
  ^[[46;1mTEXT^[[0m
where the first sequence says to diplay TEXT as bold with
a cyan background and the second sequence turns it off.

This strips the ANSI escape sequences and if the buffer is saved,
the sequences will be lost."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (region-active-p))
      (message "ansi-color-region: region is not active"))
  (if buffer-read-only
      ;; read-only buffers may be pointing a read-only file system, so don't mark the buffer as
      ;; modified. If the buffer where to become modified, a warning will be generated when emacs
      ;; tries to autosave.
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t)
            (modified (buffer-modified-p)))
        (ansi-color-apply-on-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
        (set-buffer-modified-p modified))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

The one downside is that `ansi-color-apply-on-region` removes the ANSI escape sequence characters from the buffer, so when you save, they are lost. I wonder if there's a way to hide the characters instead of stripping them?

Comment: I'm using emacs 28.2. The ansi-color-apply-on-region included now has a 3rd parameter "preserve-sequences".  Call this function with it set to "t" does what you (and I) want.

Comment: That said, the function is really slow. It would be great if it applies on the visible region only. I know a number of modes/mini-modes work this way, say linum (?)

Answer (score 1):

For this job, I defined the following minor mode which is based on `(require ansi-color)` (emacs 28.2). This minor mode runs `ansi-color-apply-on-region' lazily, i.e. only the visible part of the buffer. Hence, it does NOT freeze Emacs even if the log file is huge.

```
(defun ansi-color-after-scroll (window start)
  "Used by ansi-color-mode minor mode"
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region start (window-end window t) t))

(define-minor-mode ansi-color-mode
  "A very primitive minor mode to view log files containing ANSI color codes.

Pros: this minor mode runs `ansi-color-apply-on-region' lazily,
i.e. only the visible part of the buffer. Hence, it does NOT
freeze Emacs even if the log file is huge.

Cons: a) when the minor code is toggled off, it does not undo
what has already been ansi colorized. b) assumes the buffer
content etc. does not change. c) jumping to random places within
the buffer may incur incorrect/incomplete colorization.

How to install: put this code into your init.el, then evaluate it or
restart Emacs for the code to take effect.

How to use: in the log buffer of need run `M-x ansi-color-mode'.
Alternatively, feel free to enable this minor mode via mode hooks
so that you needn't enable it manually.

-- lgfang
"
  :global nil
  :lighter ""
  (if ansi-color-mode
      (progn 
        (ansi-color-apply-on-region (window-start) (window-end) t)
        (add-hook 'window-scroll-functions 'ansi-color-after-scroll 80 t))
    (remove-hook 'window-scroll-functions 'ansi-color-after-scroll t)))
```