# shell-mode emacs showing npm install characters weirdly

Tags: shell, emacs, npm

The shell-mode cannot display the `npm install` process; it shows:

```
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
[?25h[1A[?25l[0G
etc
```

What can be done about it? I really do like `shell-mode` otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display ANSI color codes in emacs for any mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378271/how-do-i-display-ansi-color-codes-in-emacs-for-any-mode)

Comment: @ThomasDickey It does not work / it is not the same, so I'd kindly ask you to remove the duplicate vote.

Comment: You will have to provide enough information for others to answer it, if it is really different.

Comment: @ThomasDickey All you need to do is use an `npm install` in a shell-mode buffer. You can then see the output from my question. This output does not get solved by your "duplicate" reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in init:

```
(add-hook 'commint-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setenv "PAGER" "cat")))
```

Comment: Same issue; `[?25h[?25h[1A[0G` when it is doing `npm install`