# Are there any Linux text editors that understands bash colors?

Tags: linux, bash, console, editor

I am going through some logs written by a program that normally just logs to the console. Since it outputs to bash, I see a bunch of characters which are used for coloring in bash.

Is there any text editor out there that can interpret these character sequences and display the lines in color as bash does? Would be nice to be able to search through these logs without seeing a bunch of otherwise garbage characters.

Comment: Yes, [Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23378271/1030675).

Comment: Does it need to be configured? I'm still seeing "^[[1;33;49mFoo Bar Etc" in emacs. These correspond to hex 0x5B 0x31 0x3B 0x33 0x33 0x3B 0x39 0x6D

Comment: You will find answers by searching remove ansi color codes in Bash; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296667/remove-ansi-color-codes-from-a-text-file-using-bash

Comment: @Maxthecat: Have you checked the link? It describes how to turn the feature on.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an editor you could use:

```
echo -e $(cat colorfile)
less -r colorfile
```

Or use  vim addon **AnsiEsc:**

Download the AnsiEsc.vba.gz vim scripts file from (https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=14498)

**Install details:**

Open the AnsiEsc.vba.gz vim-scripts file in vim:

```
vim AnsiEsc.vba.gz 
:so % 
:q
```

Then open your file with vim and type

```
:AnsiEsc
```